# необязательное поле EditText

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 3 `EditText`, 2 из них обязательны к заполнению, 3-й необязательно. Так вот у меня не получается сделать его необязательным.
И еще в эти `EditText`-ы можно вводить только цифры. Я сделал так, но не получается

```
if(num1 != ' ' && num2 != ' ') {
    if ((num1 > 100 || num1 <= 0) || (num2 > 100 || num2 < 0)) {
        result.setText("Ошибка! Поле имеет недопустимую оценку");
    } else {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(exam.getText().toString())) {
            result.setText("Р1 = " + num1 + "\nP2 = " + num2 + "Если на экзамене получите "
                    + res + " баллов, тогда итоговая оценка будет " + res + " баллов\n");
        } else {
            result.setText("Р1 = " + num1 + "\nP2 = " + num2 + "\nЭкзамен: "+ examen + "\nВам нужно набрать " + res1 + " баллов чтобы получить" +
                    "4(-B)\nНужно " + res2 + " баллов чтобы получить 5(-А)");
        }
    }
```

Прошу помочь

Comment: Для валидации введенных данных используйте Регулярные выражения  http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-RegExp
А по поводу не обязательного EditTex, вы же сами указываете условие(где то...) и если оно не выполняется то вы на него как-то реагируете. Просто не проверяйте 3й EditText.
P.S. Это все чем вам можно помочь исходя из вашего ответа и прикрепленного "кода".

Comment: фу, какой код некрасивый. поправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: а что из этого всего первый, второй, и третий `EditText`?

Comment: Зачем замудряться проверкой, если вы просто передаете данные с трех `editText`, и если он является пустым - то просто по ходу программы от него ничего не зависит, иначе просто напишите метод по валидации, как вам это нужно. Ленивая загрузка вам в помощь.

Comment: Вы проверяет вообще с одинарными  кавычками надо не `' '`,а `""`

Answer (score 0):

В условии если проверяете ПУСТЫЕ ПОЛЯ, то между кавычками не должно быть пробелов:

```
if(jTextField1.getText() != '' && jTextField2.getText() != '')
```

Ваше условие заведомо ложное, т. к. сравниваете с пробелами.

А по поводу чисел, я бы на Вашем месте использовал спинеры вместо текстовых полей.

Comment: А в вашем коде точно кавычки?